# How to enforce min/max/exact size of relationship collection in OneToMany and ManyToMany mappings

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have working code that has a class like this:

```
@Entity
class User {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(...)
  List<RoleA> aRoles;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(...)
  List<RoleB> bRoles;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(...)
  List<Address> addresses;
}
```

I know how to enforce at least 1 via **nullable** attribute.
However, I'm interested in if it's possible to add JPA (not database) check, constraint or validation to enforce minimum/maximum/exact number of entities in relationship.

E.g. max 3 addresses and max 10 roles A and min 2 roles B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the Bean Validation Specification (JSR-303) is the @Size annotation:

> Supported types are String, Collection, Map and arrays. Check if the annotated element size is between min and max (inclusive).

You could validate the collection:

```
@ManyToMany
@Size(max=10)
List<RoleA> aRoles;

@ManyToMany
@Size(min=2)
List<RoleB> bRoles;

@OneToMany
@Size(max=3)
List<Address> addresses;
```

Never tried tho, instinctively I would have check this with business code.

Comment: I'm checking this with business code, however I prefer to have JPA mapping and my DB (which I don't control in this case) bulletproof. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60768735/303559) from @antoine.lange because it is essentially what I was looking for.

```
class User {
  @ManyToMany
  @Size(min=1, max=1)
  List<RoleA> aRoles;
}
```

I've tested this and it works exactly as expected for inserts. However for update Hibernate doesn't call the **BeanValidationListener** in case you change just the collection. You have to change some basic attribute too as a workaround. I will follow this up on Hibernate Jira: [HHH-13898](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13898).

This sequence doesn't trigger validation:

```
existingUser.getARoles().add(role1);
existingUser.getARoles().add(role2);
userRepository.saveAndFlush(existingUser);
```

This one does (and throws **ConstraintViolationException**):

```
user.setName(newName);
existingUser.getARoles().add(role1);
existingUser.getARoles().add(role2);
userRepository.saveAndFlush(existingUser);
```